# Reloading all rows on datagridview after filter is applied

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on a winforms application with three buttons:

[image]

1. Rent - views all rows on the rent table in my db
2. Hire - views all rows on the hire table in my db
3. Overdue - filters out rows in Rent and Hire (depending on what you clicked beforehand)

However what I'm seeing is that after the Overdue filter is applied to the hire/rent table, if I click Rent/Hire again (effectively getting rid of the filter), the filter remains. So what I mean is that, if I click Rent, Overdue and then Rent, the filter from Overdue should go away but it remains. How can I resolve this?

This is my code so far:

```
    public void viewOverdue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        viewOverdue.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        DateTime overdueDate = default(DateTime);
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        string odDate = null;

        if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            overdueDate = today.AddDays(-12);
            odDate = overdueDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }
        else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        {
            overdueDate = today.AddDays(-13);
            odDate = overdueDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }
        else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            overdueDate = today.AddDays(-7);
            odDate = overdueDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }
        else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        {
            overdueDate = today.AddDays(-8);
            odDate = overdueDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }
        else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        {
            overdueDate = today.AddDays(-9);
            odDate = overdueDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }
        else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            overdueDate = today.AddDays(-10);
            odDate = overdueDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }
        else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            overdueDate = today.AddDays(-11);
            odDate = overdueDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss");
        }

        CurrencyManager manager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
        manager.SuspendBinding();
        DateTime dateBase = DateTime.Parse(odDate);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if(row.Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                DateTime dateRow = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                row.Visible = (dateRow <= dateBase);
            }
        }
        manager.ResumeBinding();
    }
}

    public void visible()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void viewHire_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        viewOverdue.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        viewHire.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        viewRent.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = hireBindingSource;
        Globals.notesTbl = "hireNotes";
        visible();
    }

    private void viewRent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        viewOverdue.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        viewHire.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        viewRent.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = rentBindingSource;
        Globals.notesTbl = "rentNotes";
        visible();
    }
```

Comment: You said it is a Web application. If yes I think you miss the `.DataBind();` after instantiate the `DataSource`

Comment: Sorry - meant to say its a winforms application

Comment: I was wondering why you have also `DataGridView`. that is why on my comment I had insisted on Web Apps

Comment: where `hireBindingSource` and `rentBindingSource` come from?

Comment: `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { this.rentTableAdapter.Fill(this.databaseDataSet.Rent); this.hireTableAdapter.Fill(this.databaseDataSet.Hire);}`

Comment: When you put a breakpoint to this line `dataGridView1.DataSource = rentBindingSource;` are those objects null?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51035/discussion-between-methuselah-and-lnanikian)